# query using subtime() unexpectedly returns no rows

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I'm using the following query:

```
 SELECT message,timestamp 
 FROM botlogs.tbllogs
 WHERE message like '%Failed to grab car amount 
       or 0 website%' and timestamp > Subtime('2011-08-01 13:20','0:60')
```

Although I have a row for 8/1/2011 1:21:53pm, the above query doesn't return any rows.  Why is that?

If I run

```
select timestamp,message 
from botlogs.tbllogs 
where message like Failed to grab car amount 
       or 0 website%' and timestamp < '2011-08-01 13:20' - INTERVAL 180 SECOND
```

it returns the error from `7/31/2011 9:27:24` pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because:

```
mysql> SELECT Subtime('2011-08-01 13:20','0:60');
+------------------------------------+
| Subtime('2011-08-01 13:20','0:60') |
+------------------------------------+
| NULL                               |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
```

Try this instead

```
mysql> SELECT Subtime('2011-08-01 13:20','00:01:00');
+----------------------------------------+
| Subtime('2011-08-01 13:20','00:01:00') |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2011-08-01 13:19:00                    |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or

```
mysql> SELECT '2011-08-01 13:20' - INTERVAL 60 SECOND;
+-----------------------------------------+
| '2011-08-01 13:20' - INTERVAL 60 SECOND |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2011-08-01 13:19:00                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: do you have an example with this is the were clause?  i added the seconds but then it return rows from a day ago.

Comment: In your query that would be: `SELECT message,timestamp FROM botlogs.tbllogs WHERE message like '%Failed to grab car amount or 0 website%' and timestamp > '2011-08-01 13:20' - INTERVAL 60 SECOND`

Comment: timestamp column is 8/1/2011 1:21:53 and even if i run that above query  with - InterVal 4 hour it still returns 0 rows, even though when i run select now() - interval 4 hour it returns 8/1/2011 11:48:46 am

Comment: You have `<` instead of `>` in your query now.

Comment: i know but if i put in > it returns 0 rows, i tell if do 180 seconds difference and it gives me something from almost a day ago?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime),

> - SUBTIME(expr1,expr2)
>
> SUBTIME() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in the same
>   format as expr1. **expr1 is a time or datetime expression, and expr2 is
>   a time expression.**

(emphasis mine)

The problem is that `0:60` is not a valid time expression:

```
mysql> select time('0:60');
+--------------+
| time('0:60') |
+--------------+
| NULL         |
+--------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect time value: '0:60' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and so the subtraction returns `NULL`:

```
mysql> select subtime(now(), '0:60');
+------------------------+
| subtime(now(), '0:60') |
+------------------------+
| NULL                   |
+------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect time value: '0:60' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `NULL`s cause your comparison to return false for every possibility, which results in 0 rows in the final result.